# Pentaho isolating subreports and reusing styles

Tags: reporting, pentaho

Rationale:
the requirement is 1 huge report containing a lot of tables and charts for different datasets (subreports).

Work on the subreports should to be divisible and among a few programmers.

Global changes at the last minute are not to require many repeated operations on all the subreports (e.g. make headers' font bold)

I am looking to achieve the following using Pentaho open source tools:

- 1 master report, integrating many sub-reports as external files
- 1 file per (sub)report
- 1 place (master report or standalone file) for most styles, reused by all subreports

Can someone point out how to set up the above file structure?